# FlaskForm multiple validations and conditional validation

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to implement validation that if one gcse/gcse_grade field is entered then the others have to be as well as they are all optional at the moment. I tried coming up with validate_fields function but it does not seem to be working. There validation to make sure user enters accepted grades but now I want to make sure they fill out all fields they need to.

form.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField , TimeField, DateField
from wtforms import TextAreaField, FileField, DecimalField, IntegerField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length, NumberRange, Optional, Regexp, AnyOf
from app.models import Application, RejectedApplication

class AddApplicationForm(FlaskForm):
    
     #participant_one = StringField('participant one', validators=[Optional(), Email()])
    gcse = StringField('Math GCSE grade', validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(values=['C', 'B' , 'A', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a*', 'A*'], message='A grade C and above is nedded to apply for this course', values_formatter=None)])
    gcse2 = StringField('English GCSE grade', validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(values=['C', 'B' , 'A', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a*', 'A*'], message='A grade C and above is nedded to apply for this course', values_formatter=None)])
    gcse3 =  StringField(' third GCSEs title', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=2, max=50)])
    gcse3_grade = StringField('third GCSE grade',validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(values=['C', 'B' , 'A', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a*', 'A*'], message='A grade C and above is nedded to apply for this course', values_formatter=None)])
    gcse4 =  StringField(' fourth GCSEs title', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=2, max=50)])
    gcse4_grade = StringField('fourth GCSE grade', validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(values=['C', 'B' , 'A', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a*', 'A*'], message='A grade C and above is nedded to apply for this course', values_formatter=None)])
    gcse5 =  StringField(' fifth GCSEs title', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=2, max=50)])
    gcse5_grade = StringField('fifth GCSE grade',validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(values=['C', 'B' , 'A', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a*', 'A*'], message='A grade C and above is nedded to apply for this course', values_formatter=None)])
    ucas = IntegerField('UCAS', validators=[Optional(), NumberRange(min=56, max=360, message='A minimum of 56 points is needed to apply for this course')])
      #staff_code = StringField('staff_code', validators=[DataRequired(), Regexp('iamstaff', flags=0, message='Wrong, please concact ... for help')])
    qaa = StringField('QAA', validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(values=['Pass', 'PASS', 'pass'], message='A Pass is nedded to apply for this course', values_formatter=None)])
    interbac = IntegerField('International Baccalaureate, Optional', validators=[Optional(), NumberRange(min=24, max=45, message='A minimum score of 24 is needed to apply for this course')]) 
    ielits = IntegerField('IELITS score', [Optional(),NumberRange(min=6, max=9,message='A minimum of score of 6 is needed to apply for this course' )])
    company = StringField('Company', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=2, max=100)])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[Optional(), Length(min=15, max=500)]) 
    start_date = DateField('Start Date', format='%m/%d/%Y', validators=(Optional(),))
    end_date = DateField('Start Date', format='%m/%d/%Y', validators=(Optional(),))
    #start_date = DateField('end Date', Optional(), format='%d/%m/%Y')
    #end_date = DateField('end Date', format='%d/%m/%Y')
    personal_statement = TextAreaField('Personal statement', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=25, max=500)])
    applicationtype_id= SelectField('Application type', coerce=int)
    name= StringField('Company', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=2, max=100)])
   #image = FileField('Add image', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit application') 



    def validate_fields(self, gcse, gcse2,gcse3_grade, gcse4_grade, gcse5_grade ):
    
        gcse=gcse.data
        gcse2= gcse2.data
        gcse3_grade= gcse3_grade.data
        gcse4_grade= gcse4_grade.data
        gcse5_grade= gcse5_grade.data
        if gcse is not None and gcse2 is None or gcse3_grade is None or gcse4_grade is None or gcse5_grade is None :
            raise ValidationError('Please enter 5 GCSE grades')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First, the class level validation method is called `validate` not `validate_fields` and it doesn't accept all the field names.

Also, your validation logic can be greatly simplified by using the inbuilt  [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function.

```
def validate_fields(self):
    gcse= self.gcse.data
    gcse2 = self.gcse2.data
    gcse3_grade = self.gcse3_grade.data
    gcse4_grade = self.gcse4_grade.data
    gcse5_grade = self.gcse5_grade.data

    grades = (gcse, gcse2, gcse3_grade, gcse4_grade, gcse5_grade)

    if any(grades) is True:
        if all(grades) is False:
            raise ValidationError('Please enter 5 GCSE grades')
```

The pseudocode reads like this:

> if at least one grade is not None, check if all grades are not None

Finally, concerning your statement:

> I tried coming up with validate_fields function but it does not seem
> to be working

Don't just "come up" with stuff. Read the documentation or code (where it's appropriate) :-) It'll save you a lot of time compared to figuring out things by yourself.